# How can i place a echo within the 'define' of another echo

Tags: php, echo

i use auto generated sections of my website a lot, and i have started to include tooltips on important features, using the define function is a must have.

so i currently have:

```
define('Raeger_PATH', '<?php echo ALIGNMENT_CRUSADER; ?>');
```

this was

```
define('Raeger_PATH', 'CRUSADER');
```

until i wanted the tooltip, so i need to add the code, now i CAN just add the code, but didnt want the same code repeated over and over so i attempted to ad the echo, but nothing appears.

So how do i place the eccho within the defination of another echo, it might not be possible, it might just require something i doont know about.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make this by:

```
define('Raeger_PATH',ALIGNMENT_CRUSADER);
```

Comment: GREAT, thanks, that worked instantly, so im guessing the call the create an echo is already present, i will accept as answer but its telling me to wait 9 minutes to do so lol